# How to use service workers in android WebView?

Tags: android, webview, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

I have created a PWA and I am opening it in the android app's WebView. The PWA opens in WebView, the service worker is also registered when the app is opened in online mode. But, when I open the app in offline mode I am not able to see ServiceWorker js file which was registered earlier. How to persist the ServiceWorker js file?

I went through Android's WebKit, there it was specified that for service worker support in WebView we need to use ServiceWorkerClient and ServiceWorkerController, but it is not clear, that, how exactly to use them with the WebView.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for native intervention in service workers you can use the ServiceWorkerController but only on webview pages that have a service worker installed.

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63491172/13737427) for a working example.